# How to find which group policy setting is preventing software from opening?

Tags: group-policy, process

I have recently installed the Lumension Device Control Management Console on a computer on my Domain. There is a GPO on the domain which is enforcing security settings and audit settings. Now that I have the software installed when I go to Open the software the EXE loads and shows up in Task manager but the window never comes up. When I disable the group policy it opens fine. Normally when the program loads it asks if you want to login to the console with domain account credentials. I am wondering if this both a network block or just a group policy setting preventing it from opening.

This is not the standard "you cannot use this program because settings are being enforced" issue that is usually prompted when you have a list of programs your preventing from running. Are there specific settings I can look for that is affecting this Windows 7 Machine from opening the management console when the GPO is Enabled? I have looked at it with Process Monitor running but I am a little confused as to where to find evidence.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by checking in event viewer at the exact time the application is blocked. Look for EventID 865 from source Software Restriction Policies in the Application event log. The details of which should be similar to the following:

```
Access to C:\WINDOWS\system32\ctfmon.exe has been restricted by your Administrator by location with policy rule {bcb5037f-a1ff-45d0-9cfc-11fae74fb878} placed on path C:\WINDOWS\system32\ctfmon.exe
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734103(v=ws.10).aspx

Your other option would be to take the time to pull the gpresult and look through each policy. Identify what file type is being blocked and do a ctl-f in the html ouput of the gpresult.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160(v=ws.11).aspx